# Unable to intall any Video Player in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: vlc

While I try to install Any video player in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I get the following message

Unable to install vlc Media player
Error while installing package : Installed systemd-shim
package post -removal script subprocess returned error exit
status 2

Comment: Message looks somewhat modified. The package name is vlc. Try to paste **exact** output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having isn't actually related to installing VLC or any other new packages, but rather it's complaining that a previously attempted package management operation has failed or is failing - in this case it appears to be `systemd-shim`

I'm not sure if you should have that `systemd-shim` package installed, so if you manually changed that, you should probably revert those changes.

You can run this command to tell the package system to finish what it was told to do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

You can also run this command to tell apt to resolve package dependencies:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken
```

Comment: When i run the command                             sudo apt install --fix-broken  i get the below error                                                              dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim